# Azure virtual machine diagnostics event log level

Tags: event-log, azure-virtual-machine, azure-diagnostics

I'm trying to configure an Azure VM (Windows Server 2012 R2) to log event logs to Azure Storage.

I've used the following .wadcfg file

```
<WadCfg>
<DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration> 
<WindowsEventLog scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Verbose" scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M">
<DataSource name="Application!*" />
</WindowsEventLog>
<PerformanceCounters scheduledTransferPeriod="PT5M">
<PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" sampleRate="PT1M" />
</PerformanceCounters>
</DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration>
</WadCfg>
```

and I've used the following powershell script to install it

```
$serviceName = "x"
$vmname = "x"
$diagnosticsFilePath = "x\diagnostics.wadcfg"
$storageName = "x"
$storageKey = (Get-AzureStorageKey $storageName).Primary
$storageAccount = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageName -StorageAccountKey $storageKey

(Get-AzureVM -ServiceName $serviceName -Name $vmname) | Set-AzureVMDiagnosticsExtension -DiagnosticsConfigurationPath $diagnosticsFilePath - StorageContext $storageAccount -Version 1.3 | Update-AzureVM
```

When I run the script without the 'scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Verbose"' it works fine. The scripts finishes and the event logs show up in storage. But when I try to run the script with the wadcfg as posted above, I get the following error in the Application Event Log on the VM, source AzureDiagnostics.

> Microsoft.Azure.Plugins.Plugin.WadConfigValidatorException: Exception when parsing configuration: Error: The 'scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter' attribute is not declared. line: 2 column: 18
>      at Microsoft.Azure.Plugins.Plugin.WadConfigValidator`1.Initialize(String configString, String schemaPath)
>      at Microsoft.Azure.Plugins.Plugin.WadParser.Parse()

followed by

> Failed to parse the WAD config file

and lastly

> DiagnosticsPlugin launch failed with exit code -106

The same thing happens if I try to include 'bufferQuotaInMB="0"' as well. I can't figure out what the problem is.

I used the following sources, among others (I could only post two links):
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cloud_solution_architect/archive/2015/01/26/azure-diagnostics-for-azure-virtual-machines.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh411551.aspx

I might have just overlooked something simple, but for now I'm stuck.

Comment: What version of the Azure SDK are you using?

Comment: I'm using Azure SDK 2.4. I've seen there are some changes regarding this in Azure SDK 2.5, but I'm not in a position to update this quite yet.